# Are these two transformations different? How?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T_0$ be a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$$
  T_0 =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
  a & b & c\\
  d & e & f\\
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

How is this *really different* from this transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

$$
  T =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is crucial to realize  the following statement:

> $\mathbb R^2$ **is not a subset** of $\mathbb R^3$. Instead, there is a way of realizing $\mathbb R^2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, via the map $i(x,y) = (x,y,0)$.

Therefore, $T_0$ and $T$ are different, simply because they take the same input to different vectors! I mean, two functions are equal if their value at every point is equal, but here some function takes values in $\mathbb R^2$, while another takes value in $\mathbb R^3$, so obviously $T_0$ and $T$ are "different" as functions.

Now, how you would like to express the "similarity" between $T_0$ and $T$ is as follows : what $T_0$ is doing, is essentially  $T$, except that it is adding this one more row of zeros. That is, for the same $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$, if $T(x,y,z) = (u,v)$, then $T_0(x,y,z) = (u,v,0)$.

So, then $i \circ T$, where I defined $i$ in the yellow box, does go from $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$, just like $T_0$. Furthermore, $i \circ T(x,y,z) = i(u,v) = (u,v,0) = T_0(x,y,z)$ for all $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3$.

> Hence, the accurate statement is : $i \circ T = T_0$ *as functions*. The "canonical" nature of $i$ as a submersion allows everybody reading this statement to realize that $T$ and $T_0$, while not being equal, are "essentially" equal.